# Can you make a Chart.js Radar Chart's Axises Individual Colors?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

Would like to make individual axises different colors, so far have found nothing even close to being able to pick out specific axises in any samples.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config for multiple axis:

```
const config = {
type: 'radar',
data: data,
options: {
  scales: {
    r: {
        angleLines: {
            color: ['rgba(45, 183, 87, 1)', 'rgba(78, 190, 235, 1)', 'rgba(78, 190, 235, 1)', 'rgba(78, 190, 235, 1)', 'rgba(255, 152, 49, 1)', 'rgba(255, 152, 49, 1)', 'rgba(255, 152, 49, 1)','rgba(96, 230, 225, 1)','rgba(96, 230, 225, 1)','rgba(96, 230, 225, 1)', 'rgba(45, 183, 87, 1)','rgba(45, 183, 87, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 5
        }
    }
  },
  elements: {
    line: {
      borderWidth: 3
    },
  }
},
```

};